# How can I see exactly what arguments are being passed through a filter so that I may modify them?

Tags: filters, actions

I'm having a great deal of trouble phrasing this.

If I were to use the filter

```
views_edit-page
```

How can I see what exactly is being passed through the filter so that I may edit them? Normally I would var_dump something similar to this, to get a breakdown of it's contents, but due to it being a filter, this does not seem to work.

For example

```
add_filter('views_edit-page','addFilter');

function addFilter($views) {
  var_dump($views);
  die();
}
```

Is what I'd like to do, so that I may see exactly what $views consists of, in order to edit them. However, this does not work, what is a method I can use in order to see the content of $views?

Comment: Do the answers at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149143/hide-the-post-count-behind-post-views-remove-all-published-and-trashed-in-cus help?

Comment: Kind of, It modified the contents of the Filter, but does not provide a way to see what the contents actually are. I don't quite understand how they are able to make modifications to the data of the filter without first being able to see what the data consists of.

Comment: Your code works for me. Make sure you're on a page where the hook actually fires. `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could push the variable contents to error log for later inspection? Like so,

```
function addFilter($views) {
    // error_log is native php function to log stuff
    // print_r prints human-readable information about a variable, 
    // print_r second parameter makes the function return result instead of echoing it
    error_log( print_r( $views, true ) );
    return $views;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `views_edit-page` filter returns an array of strings. By default this will be something like this:

```
array (
  'all' => '<a href="edit.php?post_type=page" class="current" aria-current="page">All <span class="count">(1)</span></a>',
  'publish' => '<a href="edit.php?post_status=publish&#038;post_type=page">Published <span class="count">(1)</span></a>'
)
```